# Blow up solution of a Riccati's equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, blowup

Consider the Cauchy problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x=x(t)^2+t\\
x(0)=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that its solution is not defined in $[0,3]$.

Comment: Compare this with the problem for which $\dot{x} = t$ on some interval $[0, a)$, $\dot{x} = x(t)^2$ on $(a, 3]$, and $x(0) = 0$.